# Unity how to allow object to move within a certain boundary using only coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to script a cube so that it can only move from 0-5 on the x axis. 
My cube starts at zero. I want my cube to move forward until it reaches 5, then stop and go backwards until it reaches 0, then repeat.

The problem I am getting is of course my cube stops at 5, moves back 1 step to 4 and of course it is allowed move forward again. I want it to go 0-5, then 5-0 and repeat.

**My Attempt**

```
    //Drags cube along the ground
    if (transform.position.x > 0 & transform.position.x < 5) {
        transform.Translate(1* Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

//If our cubes reaches our boundary, move it backwards
if (transform.position.x >= 5 || transform.position.x <= 0 ) {
    transform.Translate(-1, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mathf.PingPong` to oscillate between `0f` and `5f` based on the current time.

```
float speed = 1f;
float curXPosition = Mathf.PingPong(speed * Time.time, 5f);
transform.position = new Vector3(curXPosition,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
```

If you need it to start at 0 at a specific time:

```
// as class field
public float zeroTime=0f;
public float speed;

// When you want it to start from zero, call this line:
this.zeroTime = Time.time; 

// in Update/FixedUpdate
float curXPosition = Mathf.PingPong(speed * (Time.time-zeroTime), 5f);
transform.position = new Vector3(curXPosition,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
```

Comment: Okay that works but I have a problem, I have a stack of cubes which are stacked on top of each other in the editor, when I play the scene they all appear inside each other. I assume because of the vector position? I set the position to transform.position = new Vector3(curXPosition,2f,0f);

Comment: @Ninja2k Yes, you can use `transform.position = new Vector3(curXPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);` I'm updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That works perfectly but how does it know how to go backwards?

Comment: `Mathf.PingPong` is like `Mathf.Repeat` except instead of always going from `0` to `length` on every repeat, it goes the opposite direction every other repeat.  So for the first 5 seconds, it results in values [0...5] then for the next 5 seconds, it results in [5...0], And so on.